# Wordpress shortcode not displaying session data

Tags: php, wordpress, session, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I am storing form data in session because it is a multi page form.
Then I am trying to display the data using a shortcode that I create in functions.php

Here is the code for storing the data and creating the shortcode. But when I use the shortcode `[SESSION_SHORTCODE]` in my page html, it displays an empty error `Array ( )`

Any help in the right direction is appreciated. By the way, you can view live version [here](http://testwebsitepage.club/offer/).

```
function store_values_of_page_two($POST) {
 session_start();

 foreach ($POST as $key => $value) {
  $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
 }

 $newURL = site_url() . "/offer/details/results/";
 wp_redirect( $newURL );
 exit;
}


function test_shortcode(){
 session_start();
 print_r($_SESSION);
 echo $_SESSION["loan_amount2"];
 echo $_SESSION["name"];

} 
add_shortcode("SESSION_SHORTCODE","test_shortcode");
```

Comment: 2 thoughts: finish your session creation with `session_write_close()` and give your session a name with `session_name()` before `session_start()`.